# Save XLSM file to Database column and retrieve?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, c#-2.0, excel-2007

The code previously implemented takes in the xls file saves it on to a column in a table using the stream i use the same method but the only change is the the file saved is a xlsm or an xlsx type file it saves to the column in the database

When I try and get the contents from the database and throw the saved xlsm file or xlsx file I get an error "Excel file found unreadable content do you want to recover the contents of this work book ?"

Here's the code to save the xlsm or the xlsx file

```
System.IO.Stream filestream = System.IO.File.Open(file, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
int fileLength = (int)filestream.Length;
byte[] input = new byte[fileLength];
filestream.Read(input, 0, fileLength);
string Sql = "insert into upload values(@contents)";
con.Open();
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand c = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(Sql, con);
c.Parameters.Add("@contents", System.Data.SqlDbType.Binary);
c.Parameters["@contents"].Value = input;
c.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

To retrieve and send to user

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select contents from upload order by id desc", con);
SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
int bufferSize = 32768;                   
        byte[] outbyte = new byte[bufferSize];  
        long retval;                           
        long startIndex = 0;                    
        startIndex = 0;
        retval = reader.GetBytes(0, startIndex, outbyte, 0, bufferSize);
        while (retval > 0)
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(outbyte);
            startIndex += bufferSize;
            if (retval == bufferSize)
            {
                retval = reader.GetBytes(2, startIndex, outbyte, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            else
            {
                retval = 0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you perhaps show us some code, as from your description it is impossible to say what the problem might be.

Comment: Agreed, it sounds like you haven't correctly pushed the stream into the server. The most common cause is not taking due note of the return value of stream.Read(...)

Comment: Sorry the code looks bad while posted as a comment i have now edited the question with the code .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things strike me as possibilities.

Firstly, you are not calling `reader.Read()`.

Secondly, there is not need for the check on `retval == bufferSize` - just call GetBytes again and it will return 0 if no bytes were read from the field.

Thirdly, as you are writing to the HttpResponse you need to make sure that you call Response.Clear() before writing the bytes to the output, and Response.End() after writing the file to the response.

The other thing to try is saving the file to the hard drive and comparing it to the original. Is it the same size? If it is bigger then you are writing too much information to the file (see previous comments about HttpResponse). If it is smaller then you are not writing enough, and are most likely exiting the loop too soon (see comment about `retval`).

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply the points mentioned 
1. reader.Read() is used in a if statement if true then it goes to the method to read the binary data.
2.I have used the Response.Clear too 
3.I have removed the extra code which you mentions is not required the file downloads successfully but does not open i get the same error .
Is it because the new MS Excel file that is xlsx or xlsm format internally contains multiple xml files ?

Comment: The file extension should make no difference to the code. If it worked fine for a .xls, but now doesn't work for a .xlsx then it is perhaps because Excel was more forgiving of the format of an .xls file, although I doubt it.

You don't respond on the file size issue. If you are reading and writing the file correctly it should be exactly the same when you save it to disk.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't help but notice the number of places where your code failed to wrap an IDisposable in a `using` block, like the following:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    byte[] input;
    using (System.IO.Stream filestream = System.IO.File.Open(file, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
    {
        int fileLength = (int)filestream.Length;
        input = new byte[fileLength];
        filestream.Read(input, 0, fileLength);
    }
    const string Sql = "insert into upload values(@contents)";
    con.Open();
    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand c = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(Sql, con))
    {
        c.Parameters.Add("@contents", System.Data.SqlDbType.Binary);
        c.Parameters["@contents"].Value = input;
        c.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select contents from upload order by id desc", con))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
        {
            int bufferSize = 32768;
            byte[] outbyte = new byte[bufferSize];
            long retval;
            long startIndex = 0;
            startIndex = 0;
            retval = reader.GetBytes(0, startIndex, outbyte, 0, bufferSize);
            while (retval > 0)
            {
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(outbyte);
                startIndex += bufferSize;
                if (retval == bufferSize)
                {
                    retval = reader.GetBytes(2, startIndex, outbyte, 0, bufferSize);
                }
                else
                {
                    retval = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```